# Read object from JSON HTTP response

Tags: node.js

How can I read the 'name' object from the response below:

```json
{ '730':
   { success: true,
     data:
      { type: 'game',
        name: 'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive',
        steam_appid: 730,
        required_age: 0,
        is_free: true,
        controller_support: 'full',
        dlc: [Array],
        detailed_description:
         '<h1>Вышло обновление</h1><p><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/1490530/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive__Operation_Broken_Fang/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"  id="dynamiclink_0" >https://store.steampowered.com/app/1490530/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive__Operation_Broken_Fang/</a></p><br><h1>Об игре</h1>Counter-Strike: Global Offensive (CS: GO) возрождает ураганную командную игру, впервые представленную еще 19 лет назад.<br><br>CS: GO включает в себя новые карты, персонажей, оружие, игровые режимы, а также улучшенную версию классической составляющей CS (de_dust и т.п.). <br><br>«Counter-Strike была сюрпризом для игровой индустрии, когда не особо удачный мод стал одним из самых популярных шутеров в мире сразу же после его релиза в Августе 1999 года, — говорит Даг Ломбарди из Valve, — за прошедшие 12 лет, она все еще одна из самых популярных в мире игр, часто появляется на игровых соревнованиях и продана в количестве более 25 миллионов копий по всему миру. CS: GO обещает возродить знаменитый игровой процесс Counter-Strike и предложить его игрокам не только на ПК, но и на консолях следующего поколения и компьютерах Mac».',
        about_the_game:
         'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive (CS: GO) возрождает ураганную командную игру, впервые представленную еще 19 лет назад.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nCS: GO включает в себя новые карты, персонажей, оружие, игровые режимы, а также улучшенную версию классической составляющей CS (de_dust и т.п.). <br />\r\n<br />\r\n«Counter-Strike была сюрпризом для игровой индустрии, когда не особо удачный мод стал одним из самых популярных шутеров в мире сразу же после его релиза в Августе 1999 года, — говорит Даг Ломбарди из Valve, — за прошедшие 12 лет, она все еще одна из самых популярных в мире игр, часто появляется на игровых соревнованиях и продана в количестве более 25 миллионов копий по всему миру. CS: GO обещает возродить знаменитый игровой процесс Counter-Strike и предложить его игрокам не только на ПК, но и на консолях следующего поколения и компьютерах Mac».',
        short_description:
         'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive (CS: GO) возрождает ураганную командную игру, впервые представленную еще 19 лет назад. CS: GO включает в себя новые карты, персонажей, оружие, игровые режимы, а также улучшенную версию классической составляющей CS (de_dust и т.п.).',
        supported_languages:
         'чешский, датский, нидерландский, английский<strong>*</strong>, финский, французский, немецкий, венгерский, итальянский, японский, корейский, норвежский, польский, португальский, бр. португальский, румынский, русский, китайский (упр.), испанский, шведский, тайский, китайский (трад.), турецкий, болгарский, украинский, греческий, испанский Лат. Ам., вьетнамский<br><strong>*</strong>озвучивание доступно на этих языках',
        header_image:
         'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/730/header.jpg?t=1607046958',
        website: 'http://blog.counter-strike.net/',
        pc_requirements: [Object],
        mac_requirements: [Object],
        linux_requirements: [Object],
        developers: [Array],
        publishers: [Array],
        packages: [Array],
        package_groups: [Array],
        platforms: [Object],
        metacritic: [Object],
        categories: [Array],
        genres: [Array],
        screenshots: [Array],
        movies: [Array],
        recommendations: [Object],
        achievements: [Object],
        release_date: [Object],
        support_info: [Object],
        background:
         'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/730/page_bg_generated_v6b.jpg?t=1607046958',
        content_descriptors: [Object] } } }
```

I'm not dev by any means so the question for someone might sound simple but it's quite complicated for my eyes :)

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the property `730` is a number (which is an invalid property name when using dot-syntax), you'll have to use bracket-notation to access it. Then, just follow the nesting through `data` to `name`:

```js
response['730'].data.name
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying response.'730' but I need to get back to the basics it seems :)